# How to fetch each name once from all row where select row have multiple name

Tags: php, mysql

I have a movie database where i saved all data about movies. Now I want to fetch all actor list for do something more. In my `movie` table have a `cast` row where all actor/actress name separated by slash.

How can I fetch each actor/actress name once from `cast` row?

My movie table like as:

```
#############################################################
  id    ||  movie    ||   cast                          
#############################################################
  1     || Titanic   ||   Leonardo DiCaprio / Kate Winslet  
-------------------------------------------------------------
  2     || The Beach ||   Leonardo DiCaprio / Daniel York 
-------------------------------------------------------------
  3     || Quills    ||   Geoffrey Rush / Kate Winslet
```

So now I want to fetch each actor name once like as:

```
Leonardo DiCaprio
Kate Winslet
Daniel York 
Geoffrey Rush
```

I tried as below

```
$sql = "SELECT cast FROM mivie ORDER BY id ASC"; 
$execute = $db->query("$sql");
$row = $dbh->query($sql);
    while ($row = $execute->fetch_assoc()) {
    $cast = $row['cast'];
       $myArray = explode('/', $cast);
       foreach($myArray as $my_Array);
       //do something
       echo $my_Array;
}
```

Comment: Normalizing your data tables makes it far easier to work with than using separated values in a column

Comment: `$myArray = explode('/', $cast);
        $check   = array();
        foreach ($myArray as $my_Array):
         
            
            if (!in_array($my_Array, $check))
            { 
                $check[] = $my_Array;
                echo $my_Array;
               
            }

        endforeach;`

Answer (score 2):

I think you need create table "actors" and create relationship many-to-many "movie_to_actor". And then you can easy get all actors, actors for some movie etc.

You can read more about this relationship [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) and about database normalization [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)